# SP2007 Incremental crawls taking too long to complete

Tags: search, 2007, incremental-crawl

We are running incremental crawls on our SP2007 environment. There are around 3.2 million crawled items in the content source.

When we run a incremental crawl everyday, it takes an average of 17 hours to complete. Each incremental crawls adds only few thousand items to the crawled content.Why would few thousand items take 17 hours to complete everyday?

What could be the reasons for the incremental crawls to take this long to complete? Are there any ways to reduce the time taken to complete incremental crawls?

Answer (score 1):

One likely cause for this is changes to the membership of SharePoint groups on the site causing ACL changes that need to be pushed down to many/all files/items. This generally happens when you have SharePoint groups with large numbers of users added individually. If you have the option of using AD groups for membership instead of individual users, that will work better as changes to AD group membership do not require ACL updates to the search indexes.

Ref: [Troubleshooting Security Only Crawl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2009/02/08/troubleshooting-security-only-crawl/)

Comment: Makes sense.In our environment , SP groups are rarely used, rather, users are added directly to the site permissions :( .. this environment would be a nightmare to migrate for sure.